# rails form helper method: file_field?

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

you see the file_field provide a window to let the user select a certain file and upload to the server side.But what I want is just the file name.How could I just get the file name,I don't need the file itself.anything suggestion?

Comment: Since you only want the file name, and not the path or the actual file contents, you could ask the user to type the file name in to a text field.

Comment: actually,It is for me,cause I don't want to type in the file name.haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have two fields:

- hidden field to store filename
- file input to choose file

Ex:

```
<%= file_field_tag :our_file %>
<%= f.hidden :filename, :id => "hidden_filename" %>
```

little jQuery snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
    filename = $(this).val();
    $("#hidden_filename").attr("value", filename);
    # To reset file field if you don't want to uppload a file
    $(this).attr("value", "");
  });
})
```

Answer (score 5):

not sure why you would need this, but you can try this

**in your form**

```
<%= file_field :uploadfile %>
```

**and in your controller**

```
def upload
    params[:uploadfile].original_filename
    .... process the rest of this method ....
end
```

The "original_filename" will get the name of the file that is being uploaded, then you can store into the database. hope this helps

Comment: thx,but I got a question,if I do this,will the file itself uploaded to the server side?cause I just need the name of file.

Comment: @castiel no, the file will not upload, because you are only requesting the original_filename. but also checkout the answer below by fl00r, thats even better, but both should work